# I'm confused about the scope of what I can do here

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to have a new question form load after every question submit, I am loading the first question on document ready. But not sure if I should be loading the second one within the ajax form request scope and also not sure what scope to be loading the questions after that.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : baseUrl + 'online_test/loadQuestion',
        cache : false,
        success : function(html) {
            $("#question").html(html); // Insert newx question
            $('.dummy_answers').hide();
            $('.button_next').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().children('.dummy_answers').show();
            bSubmit = $('<button name="Submit" type="button" class="submit_button" value="Submit">Submit</button>');
            $(this).parent().children('button').replaceWith(bSubmit);
            bSubmit.click(function(){
                var new_url = baseUrl + 'online_test/create_question';
                $.post(new_url, function(data) {
                      //Fade Out The Current Question
                       $('#question').fadeOut('slow');
                      //Get and Fade In/Put the previous question into the created question block
                       
                      //Load the next uncreated question
                       $.ajax({
                            url : baseUrl + 'online_test/loadQuestion',
                            cache : false,
                            success : function(html) {
                                $('#question').hide();
                                $("#question").html(html);
                                $('.dummy_answers').hide();
                                $('#question').fadeIn('slow');
                            }
                       });
                     });
                
            });
            
            });
                            
        },
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try calling a function inside the ajax defined outside the ajax?

Comment: I did think about that, but thought it'd be bad practice. Won't that keep me within that particular ajax call's scope though? Apologies if that's a dumb question. :)

Comment: I did the same exact thing a few minutes ago and it works as it is supposed to. Maybe it's not really advisable but it's not a bad practice for sure, if it's limited to this piece of code.